# ASP.NET MVC 4 WebAPI PostAsJsonAsync Newtonsoft.Json error

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

In my MVC 4 Web API project stops working. It's can't find Newtonsoft.Json.
After running this code :

```
 Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = MyHttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Api/Test", MyObject).Result
```

I get message error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
>   Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I know that MS is using this as the default JSON serializer now - and it’s referenced. I tried to update Newtonsoft.Json from NuGet but I can't find it; I find "Json.Net". So I used package manager console to reinstall

```
Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json –Reinstall
```

But still doesn’t work.
Does anyone have any idea why is this going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using some outdated library that depends on an old version of JSON.NET. You could try to install the specific version of it:

```
Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 4.5.11
```

If this fails telling you that some other package requires a newer version of JSON.NET then you will need to resolve this conflict by upgrading the outdated library that you are using and which depends on JSON.NET 4.5

Comment: i get 
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:15
+ Update-Package <<<<  Newtonsoft.Json -Reinstall -Version 4.5.11
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Update-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UpdatePackageCommand

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, just get rid of the `-Reinstall` parameter - I have updated my answer.

Comment: Update-Package : Updating 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8' to 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.11' failed. Unable to find versions of 'WebGrease, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' that are compatible wit
h 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.11'.
At line:1 char:15
+ Update-Package <<<<  Newtonsoft.Json -Version 4.5.11
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UpdatePackageCommand

Comment: So yeah, as I said you will need to update the old package that you are using in your project which depends on this legacy version of JSON.NET

Comment: I removed the JSON.NET package and install old version that using in my project ....
Thank you ...

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this section in your web.config file inside `<runtime><assemblyBinding>`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: There exist in my web.config